# Unreliable 401 errors with GCM services

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented a GCM push notification service that runs on my computer (at least during development).

To do that, I basically format and send requests to `https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`.

For authentication, I obviously used a server key I generated on the Google Developers console.

I tested it and it works perfectly (the devices receive the push notification, and it's actually damn fast).

I send those push notifications several times in the day, but yesterday I faced a situation were the request sending returned a `401` (which stands for authentication required). My request was exactly the same as usual. I retried 4 times with the same result then suddenly, it worked again and returned a `200`.

I'm at loss trying to understand why this happens. According to [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#auth_error), `401` is only supposed to happen if:

> - Authorization header missing or with invalid syntax.
> - Invalid project number sent as key.
> - Key valid but with GCM service disabled.
> - Request originated from a server not whitelisted in the Server Key IPs.

None of these conditions have changed between the different calls.

Is there some kind of threshold or quota that might explain this ? Or is there a guideline regarding what to do when this happens ?

Comment: Do you have a proxy/firewall in your network? Did you trace your calls using a network analyzer like wireshark? This 401 call may come from a firewall or proxy in your path to google servers especially you are in an controlled network environment like enterprise.

Comment: @AtillaOzgur: We all work from home (and so have different networks, Internet providers) but we all faced the same issue so likely not the cause sadly.

Comment: can you add example network trace when error occurs?

Comment: We're seeing the same problem here. Several different network connections, all white-listed, and all receive intermittent 401s.

Comment: Same issue for me. First request gets succeeded, next request failed. Did you found the root cause?